# Doctrine : get object informations before flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entitymanager

I have an object "Survey" link to some "Questions" entities (One To Many association).
In my controller, I can add some Questions to this Survey.
At the end, I would like to do some stuff before any flush.

For example, first I have : Survey1 with QuestionA and QuestionB (through $Survey->getQuestions() )

At the end : Survey1 with QuestionA QuestionB and QuestionC

Problem is :

```
$Survey->getQuestions()
```

only gave me QuestionA and QuestionB before I flush. How is it possible for me to get all objects before a flush ? It is very important for me to not flush because I make a lot of tests and I don't want to commit my changes if I am not sure that everything is ok.

Comment: ¿Could post your code for adding new questions to the survey and the definitions of the entities?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use foreach loop to get all the questions:
`foreach($Survey->getQuestions() as question){
//1st iteration you'll have QuestionA...
//2nd QuestionB...
}`